# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'question' in 'field list'")

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

After `php artisan db:seed` I am getting error:

```
1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'question' in 'field list'")
      F:\Projects\php\realtimeApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452

2   PDO::prepare("insert into `replies` (`body`, `question`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")"
```

Here is my Github repo: https://github.com/hevzy86/realtimeApp

Comment: You should post code to the question as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not as a link to the whole project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **replies** table migration, you create a field called `question_id`:

```
Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned(); // <--- here

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

However, in your migration, which depends on the Factory you have created for **replies**, you are setting the field to `question`:

```
$factory->define(Reply::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'body' => $faker->text,
        'question' => function(){  // <--- here
            return Question::all()->random();
        },
        'user_id' => function(){
            return \App\User::all()->random();
        },
    ];
```

Change the `question` in your factory to call an `id` (figure out which questions are already in the db, and just pull a random `id`) and name it correctly according to the field (`question_id`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your data base is not properly imported/or structured ( i.e. you could indeed have missing or properly named columns) You can back up and delete to start over with database.
Suggest you check data base, and (start over) try importing Data Base again and ensure it checks Ok (for instance: all green ticks if you using phpMyadmin) as quite often problems can occur when transferring databases over.  (Test it on a different PC if you could)